# How to remove Mathematica menu from xfce applications menu?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, menu, mathematica

How can I remove the Wolfram Mathematica menu from the Xfce applications menu? The Mathematica menu doesn't show up in alacarte... I'm using Xubuntu 12.10 64-bit.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by running

```
sudo xdg-desktop-menu uninstall wolfram-all.directory wolfram-mathematica8.desktop
```

Note: Make sure to save the wolfram-mathematica8.desktop somewhere just in case so you can put it back in the /usr/share/applications/ folder.

Comment: In case you don't get a better answer, come back and [accept your own](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/117/25656). If a better one does come along, you can always un-accept one and accept the other.

Comment: @vasa1 I am unable to accept my answer now because it hasn't been two days since I posted this question